# How do I use createdump on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dump

Did anyone ever manage to generate dumps by using `createdump` on Windows?

While most related documents are around Linux, in the [official document](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md#windows) talking about `createdump` it is said that this utility and the [environment variables](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md#configurationpolicy) are supported on Windows:

> **Windows**
>
> As of .NET 5.0, createdump and the below configuration environment
> variables are supported on Windows. It is implemented using the
> Windows MiniDumpWriteDump API. This allows consistent crash/unhandled
> exception dumps across all of our platforms.

However when I tried `set COMPlus_DbgEnableMiniDump=1` and then trigger a crash, there is no dump file generated. I also tried using the default location `%TEMP%\dump.%p.dmp` or a customized folder such as `D:\Dumps\%e.%p.dmp` but still no luck.

In Twitter there is a posting talking about [using createdump with NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM](https://twitter.com/bopin2020/status/1366400799199272960), but I think that `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is far too much for this.